# Celery sqs tries to connect to amqp: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//

Tags: django, celery

I want to use Celery with SQS. But, connection error is `amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//` .
What's wrong is my setting?

```
celery[sqs]         ==4.4.7  
kombu               ==4.6.11  
billiard            ==3.6.3.0
```

```
broker_url = 'sqs://%s:%s@' % (safequote(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID), safequote(AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY))
broker_transport_options = {
    'region': 'ap-northeast-1',
    'visibility_timeout': 3600,
    'polling_interval': 1,
    'queue_name_prefix': 'pre-',
}

result_backend = None
accept_content = ['pickle']
beat_schedule = {
    "add": {
        "task": "tests.tasks.insert_task",
        "schedule": crontab(minute=0, hour='*', day_of_week='0,5,6'),
    },
}
```

Comment: How did you fix this @naohide_a? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your celery connection options are wrong. Celery is trying to connect to rabbitmq. I'd suggest setting `broker_transport` to `sqs` and see if it's still working.